# Prevent scrolling entire window when hovering description in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

If I hover over a function or variable to read its description and try scrolling to the bottom, it scrolls the entire window once I reach the bottom:

[image: GIF of scrolling behaviour]

Is there a way of disabling this behaviour?

Comment: Better file a feature request in the vscode repo on Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there's a fix for this in the 'Stable' version of VSCode, but testing with the ['Insiders'](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) version, it's been fixed so I guess it'll be included in the next update.